# How to get the value of an instance stored in a list

Tags: python

I want to know how to get all the values ​​of student0 instance without using the `print(student0.name, student0. age)` method when I have the code below.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
student0 = Student("Lee", "22")
student1 = Student("Kim", "23")
```

Comment: Neither of your instances is stored in a list, `student0` is the only reference you have to that object. And please note https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing.

Comment: It's a little vague for me. Do you want to find all instances of the Student class?

Comment: Hi peter!!

I want to know how to print the values ​​(name, age) of the student0 instance.
print(student0.name, student0.age) x -> outher way

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code :

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        
    def __repr__(self): 
        return "% s % s" % (self.name, self.age) 
student0 = Student("Lee", "22")
student1 = Student("Kim", "23")
print(student0)
```